# Heat Pump on continuous duty or put in a rest period

Tags: heat-pump

I have some hybrid hot water tanks - heat pumps - that are running continuously as the demand is higher than the units can supply.

Would it be better to have a rest period baked into the schedule or have them run continuously.  These are residential units running and the warranty gets derated from 10 years to 1 year if run in a commercial setting.

The general question is, a heat pump is mostly a fan and a compressor, some things wear out quicker from cycles (on/off) like pumps while others can potentially overheat if running continuous.

I could put an electrical cutoff switch and force the tanks to turn off for a rest period each day or even multiple times a day I am just not clear on if this would help or hurt.

This is the unit that I have running, it pre-charges water before entering a gas hot water tank, I set it to eco mode so the electric element never fires up.

https://www.rheem.com/product/professional-prestige-proterra-hybrid-electric-water-heater-proph80-t2-rh375-so/

Thank you for the thoughts.

Comment: Why is it running continuously? What do the instructions and labeling say about the use to which you are putting it?

Comment: Some devices are build for continuous mode. The frequent stop and start is not good. The start mode usually applies more pressure and lovers the life time.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, demand is higher than the units can supply so they run continuous.  Instructions say nothing about continuous operation.